# Можно ли скрыть дефолтные метки инфраструктуры в API яндекс карты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, есть ли в API Яндекс карт возможность убрать дефолтные метки инфраструктуры?

[image: То что нужно убрать]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрыть их нельзя, можно только отключить интерактивность опцией карты `yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true`.

[Подробнее в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity)